# Table 'database_name.CTE' doesn't exists, when I'm using JPA(hibernate) with native query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA(hiberbate) with native query (MySQL).

Sample query is :

```
    with cte1 as 
    (
      select ~ 
      from table1
    )
    , cte2 as
    (
      select ~ 
      from table2
    )
    , cte3 as
    (
      select ~
      from cte1
        inner join cte2 on cte2.id = cte1.id
    )
    select * 
    from cte3
```

The query do work in DB tool, But don't work in JPA(hibernate)

I got some logs like `Table 'o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : database_name.cte3' doesn't exist`

Thus I want to know how to remove database name when i'm using native query in JPA(hibernate).
Any other solutions or hints also would be helpful for me.

Comment: We need more details to help you here. Please add the full stack trace and show how you invoke this query.

Comment: Sorry, I can't add more details because the details are confidential. But I found what is the problem. The reason of the problem is that "countQuery" was not defined. I should have specified "countQuery" for Query annotation.